# iOS SQLite Phone Gap db transaction doesnt wait for callback

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

Am using [SQLite Phonegap plugin for iOS](https://github.com/brodyspark/PhoneGap-SQLitePlugin-iOS).

For db transaction statements, in iOS devices, callbacks are not getting called.

Say I have:

```
db.transaction(function (tx) {
  tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM foo", [], function(tx, ,res){
    console.log(res.rows.item(0).bar);
  });
});

console.log("lorem");
```

Output will be:

```
lorem
foo_bar_select_all
```

Why is this happening like this? Its not waiting for callback of transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it exactly what you want? the `tx.executeSql` returns imediatally, dispatching the sql code to another thread.

Comment: This works fine when Inserting or Updating, but while selecting any data from db, I need to wait for callback so that I can return the value fetched from database, if control is lost I cannot return the value. Any clues ?